SSRS Matrix Count if Matrix Value > 35
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have this matrix that counts the number of students each period. I want a column next to the matrix that counts how many periods have more than 35 students. I have tried so many formulas but nothing works. It seems so simple but nothing works. Does anyone know how to do this?
I tried
=Count(IIF(Fields!SN.Value)>"35", 1, 0)
and
=Count(IIF(Fields![Count(SN)].Value, "Per">"35",1,0))
and
=Count(IIF(Fields![Count(SN)].Value>"35",1,0))
and
=IIF(Count(Fields![Count(SN)].Value>"35",1,0))

I'm not sure you can do this (but it's Friday so I might not be thinking straight. As you need to reference 2 scopes (period and Teacher) then you can't do this in a normal expression. You might be able to solve it using some custom VB code but I would normally do this in the dataset query. If this might be an option, edit your question post a sample of your dataset data (as text please, not an image)

A simple alternative might be to highlight the textboxes that are over 35.

Thank you for the feed back. I do have the periods highlighted if they are over 35 students. Teachers are only allowed 1 period over 35 so I would like the column next to the Matrix to show how many periods went over 35. It seems so easy but I'm just not coming up with the answer.

There are some things SSRS is terrible for, this is one of them. As I said though, it's probably really easy to calculate in the dataset query so post some sample data and I'm sure myself or somebody will be able to help.

Thank you for your help. I am currently using formulas in Excel but was hoping to automate the task.
